# How to copy and paste "Over the Cells" images using Google apps script?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy and paste the images that are 'over the cell' to another sheet. I am trying to create a dashboard where users can select the title which are written in "Alt text" of the images. And the image will appear on the dashboard which will also be over the cell. I have searched the [class OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image) but there is no any option to copy and paste over the cell images.

We can obviously put the images in cells but that is not what I am looking for.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The following image is a test of dashboard I am trying to create. The images are over the cell. Column 'H' and column 'I' are the result of script. column 'G' is list of "alt text" of images. and I want to copy and paste those images using script.

[image]

Comment: Where are you adding the images from? Uploading them? From a URL? From Drive?

Comment: For this test, I have added the image from drive. We can add the images with IDs too but I was just wondering if we could  copy images in a sheet when we don't have any Ids or URLs provided. For example, when one user uploads the image directly into the sheets , and another user checks the info using dashboard. Then in such case how would we copy the images?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're trying to do is currently possible.

The class [OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image) was released [quite recently](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2018#october_30_2018) and there is no way to retrieve the Blob for such images. There is actually an [open Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119800855) in Issue Tracker regarding this. Since there is no [BlobSource interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) related to this class, there is no way to get a reference of that image, if you have uploaded it from your device. And currently there is also no way to retrieve the image via Sheets API.

Theoretically, if you add the image via URL, it would be possible to get the URL via [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#getUrl()) and insert it to the sheet via [insertImage(url, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(String,Integer,Integer)), but `getUrl` doesn't seem to be working reliably, at least for some images (there is an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122429709) in Issue Tracker to tackle this).

#### Workaround (of a sort):

The only thing I can think of is manually adding the URL somewhere it can be accessed (for example, in the image description), and use that URL to insert the image in the other sheet. Then, you could use a function along these lines:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();
  var editedSheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.getA1Notation() === "G7" && editedSheet.getName() === "Destination" && value != "") {
    // Remove previous images from "Destination" sheet:
    var currentImages = editedSheet.getImages();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentImages.length; i++) {
      currentImages[i].remove();
    }
    // Get correct url from "Origin" sheet:
    var origin = e.source.getSheetByName("Origin");
    var images = origin.getImages();
    var blob;
    for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
      if (images[j].getAltTextTitle() === value) { // Check if "Alt text" matches the dropdown value
        url = images[j].getAltTextDescription(); // Get url (first added in description)
        break;
      }
    }
    // Insert new image in "Destination":
    editedSheet.insertImage(url, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

I hope this is of any help.